# Does exception handling exist in Fortran?

Tags: exception, error-handling, fortran

Is there any exception handling structure in Fortran, just like in Python?

```
try:
    print "Hello World"
except:
    print "This is an error message!"
```

If it does not exist, what would be the easiest way to handle exceptions?

Comment: As a Fortran programmer since the 70s I can confidently state *What's an exception ?*

Comment: Are you sure you require FORTRAN 77? Did exceptiins exist in any programming language in 1977? It is 40 years ago!!!

Comment: can you show an example of where you would want to use it?

Comment: This makes me so sad.  It's such a lame reason to have to give up an otherwise decent language, but I need to be able to unit test my exceptions!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Exceptions as such do not exist in Fortran, so no, there is no Exception handling.

But you can do something similar to Exception handling using Standard Fortran - there's even a paper on it [Arjen Markus, "Exception handling in Fortran"](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2502933&dl=ACM&coll=DL&CFID=850180338&CFTOKEN=61525401).

The most common notation is to use an (integer) return variable indicating the error code:

```
subroutine do_something(stat)
    integer :: stat
    print "Hello World"
    stat = 0
end subroutine
```

and in the main program do

```
call do_something(stat)
if (stat /= 0) print *,"This is an error message!"
```

---

There are other ways described in the paper such as defining a dedicated derived type for exceptions that is capable of also storing an error message. 
The example mentioned there that gets closest to an Exception is using alternate returns for subroutines (not possible with functions, though):

```
subroutine do_something(stat, *)
    integer :: stat
    !...

    ! Some error occurred
    if (error) return 1
end subroutine
```

and in the main program do

```
try: block
    call do_something(stat, *100)
    exit try ! Exit the try block in case of normal execution
100 continue ! Jump here in case of an error
    print *,"This is an error message!"
end block try
```

Please note that the block construct requires a compiler compliant with Fortran 2008.

I've never seen something like this out there, though :)

Answer (score 4):

There are proposals (see Steve Lionel's comment below) to add exception handling to the next Fortran standard. See here for example: [Exception handling - BCS Fortran Specialist Group](http://www.fortran.bcs.org/2017/BCS17b.pdf)

This has apparently a long history in Fortran (again see Steve's second comment below)

Comment: Well, no. Exception handling is one of many suggestions for the next standard. There have been proposals for it in the past that did not go anywhere.There are NO "tentative plans" at this point for the next standard - the committee is soliciting requests from the user base, and exceptions are indeed a "candidate". See https://wg5-fortran.org The survey closes at the end of this month. J3 will start weeding through the requests at its February meeting.

Comment: John Reid has the wrong site when he mentions the old proposal - 94-258r4 was a J3 paper, not WG5. http://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/94/94-258r4.txt It IS on the WG5 site, as N1042, but the J3 link is easier to read.

Comment: The document seems to have been removed at J3, but it's still at WG5: https://wg5-fortran.org/N001-N1100/N1042.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Considering that a great deal of `try-except` use cases are for I/O handling, you should know that all FORTRAN I/O functions have an `ERR` specifier which points to a line label in the case an error happens. For example:

```
C2345678
      READ( UNIT=5, FMT=10, ERR=30, IOSTAT=N ) X
   10 FORMAT(I5) 

      WRITE( UNIT=6, FMT=20, ERR=30, IOSTAT=N ) X
   20 FORMAT(I5)

   30 WRITE( *, * ) 'I/O error # ', N, ', on 1'
```

of course one could replace the `WRITE` executable with any other expression to achieve some form of `except` functionality.

**P.S.** source of examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnat/index.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnbs/index.html).

Comment: I would note that the ERR specifier (and statement labels altogether) is quite an obsolete style and modern style is to use the IOSTAT and IOMSG specifiers.

Comment: true. I was actually careful to write FORTRAN not Fortran.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement exception handling in Fortran 2003
without resorting to the alternate return statements in Arjen Markus's solution.
The idea is to use the final procedure of a type that stores the exceptions.

A basic implementation is

```fortran
module exception_mod
   implicit none

   type exception_stack_t
      ! should contain a list of raised exceptions, 
      ! but keep it simple for this example
      logical :: raised = .false.
   contains
      final :: error_if_uncaught
   end type

contains
   subroutine raise(e)
      ! should take an exception as a dummy argument, and add it to the stack.
      type(exception_stack_t), intent(out) :: e

      e%raised = .true.
   end subroutine

   logical function catch(e) result(was_raised)
      ! should catch a particular type of exception that is passed to this procedure
      type(exception_stack_t), intent(inout) :: e

      was_raised = e%raised
      e%raised = .false.
   end function

   subroutine error_if_uncaught(this)
      type(exception_stack_t), intent(in) :: this

      if (this%raised) error stop "EXCEPTION was not caught"
   end subroutine
end module
```

and an example of raising an exception is

```fortran
   subroutine my_sqrt(x,sqrt_x,e)
      real, intent(in) :: x
      real, intent(out) :: sqrt_x
      type(exception_stack_t), optional, allocatable, intent(inout) :: e

      type(exception_stack_t), allocatable :: my_e

      if (x < 0) then
         allocate(my_e)
         call raise(my_e)
         ! should push exception `my_e` to the stack `e`
         if (present(e)) call move_alloc(my_e, e)
         return
      endif

      sqrt_x = sqrt(x)
   end subroutine
```

Now you can call this in several ways,
assuming

```fortran
real :: sqrt_x
type(exception_stack_t), allocatable :: e
```

1. Regular call:

   ```fortran
   call my_sqrt(-1.0,sqrt_x)
   ```

   prints *"EXCEPTION was not caught"*,
   due to the `my_e` local variable in `my_sqrt`.
2. Calling without catching the exception:

   ```fortran
   call my_sqrt(-1.0,sqrt_x,e)
   ```

   gives *"EXCEPTION was not caught"*
   once `e` goes out of scope.
3. Equivalent of a try-except block:

   ```fortran
   call my_sqrt(-1.0,sqrt_x,e)
   if (catch(e)) then
      print "(a)", "ValueError for 'my_sqrt', but I'm continuing."
   else
      print "(a,f0.10)", "sqrt = ", sqrt_x
   endif
   ```

   which gives
   *"ValueError for 'my_sqrt', but I'm continuing."*

This is different from using an error-indicating integer,
because

1. the caller does not have to remember to check the error status
   (the `final` procedure will do that);
2. `exception_stack_t` could store a list of raised exceptions,
   and it could be passed along procedures that call each other.
   Exceptions can be caught at any level.

You could also define a whole hierarchy of exception types.

In principle it would be possible to create the same exception architecture as in Python,
though it would be used with a very different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a proper "exception handling" I found practically useful the following subroutine

```
SUBROUTINE RAISE_EXCEPTION(message)
  INTEGER i
  CHARACTER(LEN=*) message
  PRINT *,message
  i=1
  i=1/(i-i)
ENDSUBROUTINE
```

that can be called when an error condition occurs, e.g.

```
IF (var<0) CALL RAISE_EXCEPTION('Error: var should be positive!')
```

If the code is compiled with gfortran `-ffpe-trap=zero`  and `-fbacktrace` options (`-fpe0` with ifort), the code will be stopped (because of the intentional division by zero in the subroutine) and a call stack will be printed. Moreover, if you are debugging the code, the process won't be killed (even if the execution is halted) so you can explore variables, call stack etc. from inside the debugger.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just issue `STOP` or `ERROR STOP` when you want to abort the program anyway? Exceptions are much more than just aborting the program and optionally printing the stacktrace. It is about handling the exceptions and doing something useful when they happen and continuing the program.

Comment: STOP would halt the program and terminate the associated process. So, if you are debugging the code you wouldn't be able to see anything about variables content and call stack. By the way, I agree with you that this solution is not exactly what is called exception handling, because the only "handling" it does is to stop execution.